# setTimeout is causing infinite while loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, while-loop, infinite-loop

This is my first time using a while loop in a practical application so please forgive my ignorance.

I am creating a webpage that demonstrates the costs of using a lightbulb over time.

At this stage I am trying to use a while loop to update and display the number of hours that have passed since the user clicked the light switch. (1 hour represents 1 second of realtime)

When I set breakpoints on firebug, everything operates normally until I get to the setTimeout method within my while loop. After it breaks at the setTimeout method and I click continue, it immediately breaks at the same place again, without actually executing anything else.

When I don't set breakpoints, it freezes firefox and I have to stop script execution.

I rechecked to make sure that I am using setTimeout properly. Now I'm not even sure where to check or what to search for because I don't understand whats going wrong. Even just a hint of what I might check or research would be immensely helpful.

I have tried to comment the code as verbosely as possible. I'll be happy to clarify something if needed.

I would highly recommend taking a look at the jsfiddle:

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/loweryaustin/tdS3A/19/)

But here is my code:

My JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //set image to default off position
    $('#lightswitch').css("background-image", "url(http://www.austinlowery.com/graphics/offswitch.png)");

    // setup the lifetime hours of the lightbulb for later use
    var lifetimeHours = 0;
    // setup function to update the calculated lifetime hours number on the webpage to
    // be called later
    function updateLifetimeHoursHtml (lifetimeHours) {
        $('#lifetimeHours').html(lifetimeHours);
    }
    // set up function to to send to setTimeout
    function updateNumbers () {
        // increment lifetimeHours by one
        lifetimeHours = lifetimeHours++;
        // call function to update the webpage with the new number result
        updateLifetimeHoursHtml(lifetimeHours);
    }

    // When the lightswitch on the webpage is clicked, the user should see the
    // lifetime hours update every second until the user clicks the switch again
    // which will then display the off graphic and pause the updating of the lifetime
    // hours
    $('#lightswitch').click(function(){
        // if the lightswitch is off:
        if ($('#lightswitch').attr('state') == 'off') {
            // set switch to on
            $('#lightswitch').attr('state', 'on');
            // update graphic to reflect state change
            $('#lightswitch').css("background-image", "url(http://austinlowery.com/graphics/onswitch.png)");
            // start updating the lifetime hours number on the webpage
            // while the #lightswitch div is in the on state:
            while ($('#lightswitch').attr('state') == 'on'){
                //call update numbers every second
                setTimeout('updateNumbers()', 1000);
            }
        // the lightswich was not in the off state so it must be on
        }else{
            // change the state of the switch to off
            $('#lightswitch').attr('state', 'off');
            // update graphic to reflect state change
            $('#lightswitch').css("background-image", "url(http://austinlowery.com/graphics/offswitch.png)");
        };
    });
});
```

My HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="lightswitch" state="off">&nbsp;</div>
        <span>After </span><span id="lifetimehours">0</span><span> lifetime hours:</span>
        <br><br>
        <span><b>You have spent:</b></span>
        <br><br>
        <span id="dollaramoutelectricity"></span><span> on electricty</span>
        <br>
        <span id="mainttime"></span><span> on maintenace</span>
        <br>
        <span id="dollaramountbulbs"></span><span> on replacement bulbs</span>
        <br><br>
        <span><b>You have:</b></span>
        <br><br>
        <span>Produced </span><span id="amountgreenhousegasses"></span><span> of greenhouse gasses</span>
        <br>
        <span>Sent </span><span id="amounttrash"></span><span> of trash to the dump</span>
        <br>
        <span>Used </span><span id="amountelectricty"></span><span> of electricity</span>

</div>
```

Comment: `while( stuff ){ setTimeout( ... ) }` - you set infinite timeouts this way - try with `if`.

Comment: A bit off topic but there's no need for so many comments.  Anyone reading `$('#lightswitch').attr('state', 'on');` will know you're setting the switch to `on` without having a comment explaining it.  They just clutter up the code.

Comment: That call to `setTimeout()` won't work - you need to pass just the name of the function, not that string. (Won't really work anyway, but that's a part of the problem.)

Comment: @moonwave99 Sorry but I don't quite understand what you mean? Are you saying that when I put setTimeout in a while loop it creates an infinite timeout? Are you also reccomending that I replace the while loop with an if statement? If so I don't know how to continuously update the hour count on the webpage with just an if statement. I think that requires a loop of some sort.

Comment: @Austin No loop - that doesn't work in javascript. You set a timer instead. Read my commentary to you in my answer.

Comment: @peacemaker Haha Very true (: sorry I was quickly and mindlessly commenting everything possible to make it easier for people to read. I didn't consider how useless some of them were. I'll go back and edit out some of the really pointless ones.

Comment: @Austin Your code is equivalent to `a=1; label1: a=a+1; goto label1` You newer exit the loop!

Comment: @Austin `setTimeout` returns IMMEDIATELY. It just queue the function to be called later, it DON'T wait 1000 ms and execute it and then returns. There isn't a `wait` nor `sleep` in javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var switchTimer;

$('#lightswitch').click(function(){
    if ($('#lightswitch').attr('state') == 'off') {
        $('#lightswitch').attr('state', 'on');
        switchTimer = setInterval(updateNumbers, 1000);
    } else {
        $('#lightswitch').attr('state', 'off');
        $('#lightswitch').css("background-image", "url(http://austinlowery.com/graphics/offswitch.png)");
        clearInterval(switchTimer);
    };
```

Javascript is an event based language. This means that codes doesn't run constantly. It only runs when there is an event. By using a while loop you have basically frozen it - the javascript is constantly running inside that loop. That's fine for languages like C, which have to have something running all the time.

But it's a mistake for javascript. For javascript you have to code it to respond to an event, then stop. The setInterval constantly generates an event for you, running a function every xx milliseconds.

In between runs of the timer no code is running! This is important to remember.

Comment: That `setInterval()` call won't work as written - it should be `setInterval(updateNumbers, 1000);`

Comment: @Pointy Thanks! I was rushing trying to get the answer in and didn't check things.

Comment: Thanks so much, you not only solved my problem with an example, you also gave me insight on how javascript works and compared it with other types of languages. I didn't know about event based paradigms or any of the others and since you mentioned it I was able to look it up and familiarize myself with it. I also only skimmed through the definitions of setTimeout and setInterval initially and didn't understand the difference. Now I know! Oh and it is actually clearInterval instead if cancelInterval. Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript uses an event loop.  Because your `while` loop never yields (`#lightswitch`'s `state` will forever be `on` because the infinite loop locks the UI, preventing the user from turing it off), the event loop never runs again, and the callback you register with `setTimeout` never gets a chance to execute.

What you're really looking to do is update your counter with a `setInterval` function.

```
setInterval(updateNumbers, 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it helped me better understand how Javascript works!

Answer (score 1):

Based on yngum's answer,

I think it's better like this:

```
if ($('#lightswitch').attr('state') == 'off') {
    $('#lightswitch').attr('state', 'on');
    $('#lightswitch').css("background-image", "url(http://austinlowery.com/graphics/onswitch.png)");
    updateNumbers();
}
```

And then

```
function updateNumbers () {
    lifetimeHours++;
    updateLifetimeHoursHtml(lifetimeHours);
    if($('#lightswitch').attr('state') == 'on'){
        setTimeout(updateNumbers,1000);
    }
}
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/tdS3A/24/

But if you want maximum precision, you should store `new Date().getTime()`, because doing `setTimeout` or `setInterval` of 1 second doesn't ensure you that it will be called each second...

```
function updateNumbers () {
    // call function to update the webpage with the new number result
    updateLifetimeHoursHtml(lifetimeHours+(new Date().getTime()-timerStart)/1000);
    // call updateNumbers() again
    if($('#lightswitch').attr('state') == 'on'){
        timer=setTimeout(updateNumbers,1000);
    }
}
$('#lightswitch').click(function(){
    // if the lightswitch is off:
    if ($('#lightswitch').attr('state') == 'off') {
        // set switch to on
        $('#lightswitch').attr('state', 'on');
        // update graphic to reflect state change
        $('#lightswitch').css("background-image", "url(http://austinlowery.com/graphics/onswitch.png)");
        // update the lifetime hours number on the webpage
        timerStart=new Date().getTime();
        timer=setTimeout(updateNumbers,1000);
        // the lightswich was not in the off state so it must be on
    }else{
        // change the state of the switch to off
        lifetimeHours+=(new Date().getTime()-timerStart)/1000;
        clearTimeout(timer);
        $('#lightswitch').attr('state', 'off');
        // update graphic to reflect state change
        $('#lightswitch').css("background-image", "url(http://austinlowery.com/graphics/offswitch.png)");
    };
});
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/tdS3A/26/

Even if you want the number with maximum precision because you want the calculations to be precise, maybe you want to round that value when you show it to the user. Then, use

```
function updateLifetimeHoursHtml (lifetimeHours) {
    $('#lifetimehours').html(Math.round(lifetimeHours));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I like your approach!

Answer (score 0):

Since setTimeout is generally preferred over setInterval, another solution is

Change

```
while ($('#lightswitch').attr('state') == 'on'){
    //call update numbers every second
    setTimeout('updateNumbers()', 1000);
```

To

```
setTimeout(function() {  
    updateNumbers();
    if ($('#lightswitch').attr('state') == 'on') 
        setTimeout(arguments.callee, 1000);
    }, 0);
```

This will check ur lightswitch every second, and stop when it is off.